# JS trapped in while loop

Tags: javascript

New to JS, and web programming.

I have an image moving in the horizontal axis on a canvas. WHen the image gets to a certain point I want it to stop, scale and then rotate. The method i'm using causes an infinite loop and I can't see why.

Here's the method being called

```
 while(this.getScale()<= this.mScale * 5)
        this.mScale += 0.5;

 while(this.getRotation() <= 360)
        this.mRotation += 5;

this.mX += 10; 

 if(this.goingRight){
        this.mX += 5;
    }
    else
        this.mX -=5;
```

And here's where it's called

```
update()
...
if(this.mX >400 && this.mX < 403)
        this.rotateAndScale();
```

I'm from a C#/C++ background so this in my eyes should have the effect of halting the execution of the sprite moving left or right until it's been scaled and rotated.

Get rotation:

```
Sprite.prototype.getRotation = function(){
    return this.mRotation;
};
```

Cheers for your time!

Comment: Which loop are you stuck in?

Comment: Are you trying to animate ?

Comment: Hi there, can you post how getRotation is being defined?

Comment: @RCV Yeah it's part of an animation

Comment: Your second loop is equivalent to `this.mRotation = 360 + this.mRotation%5`.

Comment: A loop is not appropriate for animation, instead you should use a [timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Timers), [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval), tho, not sure about the thing you are dealing with.

Comment: Logic error as this.mScale will never be less than this.mScale * 5 - cheers everyone/moonShadow.  @RCV I didn't add the * time to the increments to save cluttering the page - i'm using requestAnimationFrame and moving object according to time

Comment: Also @RCV I'm pretty sure all animations are dealt with with loops. With requestAnimationFrame/whatever inside a gameloop (draw/update)

Comment: You have to do things differently in Javascript, because browsers don't render anything until you return to the main event loop.  If you modify the DOM in a loop, you don't see the intermediate states, just the final result.

Comment: @Fendorio, you can't do [same thing](http://jsfiddle.net/6Fx63/) using a `while/for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not posted the definition of `this.getScale()`; however, I am guessing it's simply `return this.mScale`..? If so,

```
while(this.getScale()<= this.mScale * 5)
    this.mScale += 0.5;
```

will never terminate - the condition can never become false

Comment: Haha cheers logic error, I have a var stored as originalScale at the top of the method - meant to * that by 5. Thank you! lol